# Can't connect to SimpleHTTPServer's server created by raspberry pi Zero

Tags: python, raspberry-pi-zero

I'm using python's SimpleHTTPServer module to create a simple server on the Raspberry pi Zero. This is the command line I used:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

The problem is that I cannot connect to the server that was created. I wonder is it because the raspberry can't handle running a server or is there some setting that I missed. Thanks lot!

Comment: The Raspberry Pi can definitely run a web server (especially one as simple as SimpleHTTPServer). There can be many reasons why you can't connect (wrong address, firewall, different network). You need to provide more details (such as the error message).

Comment: I'm running the server on the same network as my connecting device and there was no firewall. Please tell me how can I fix it. Thanks alot!

Comment: You need to add more details about your problem. Can you access the service locally (from the Pi itself on port 8000)? Do you have any error messages when running the service? What error do you get on your connecting device?